# Account linking flow doesn't start on Google Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In the integration window with Google Assistant on Dialogflow (attached image), I checked "required" in the Default Welcome Intent (this is a test), but in the Actions On Google simulator the flow of account linking does not start.

[Dielogflow settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Nml.png)

I have also attached the image showing that the account linking is active in the Actions On Google console.

[Actions On Google Console settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8xvO.png)

Note: if I implement the same dynamic from Actions Builder everything works fine.

I am waiting for a reply.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screen shot that shows what happens when you do try it from the simulator? Does it do the same when testing on a real device?

Comment: Simply, when I start the action, the account linking flow does not start, but it shows the normal response (as if no account linking was set).
Yes, I also tried doing an Alpha version deploy and with the physical device.